# php gd : image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: php, gd

I'm very annoyed with this error :

If I comment out the

```
require_once'../class/myclass.class.php';
```

the image is displayed.
If I un-comment my line calling myclass.class.php, I have this message:

```
"The image "http://..." cannot be displayed because it contains errors."
```

My code is simple:

myclass.class.php :

```
<?php    
class myclass {
  public function getPanelData( $model ){
    $aFieldsData = array(
      'PAN35'=>array(
        'col'=>1,
        'row'=>3,
        'v-font'=>10,
        'v-marge-top'=>0,
        'v-marge-right'=>1,
        'v-marge-bottom'=>0,
        'v-marge-left'=>1
      )
    );
    if( key_exists($model, $aFieldsData) )
      return $aFieldsData[$model];
    else
      return false;
    }
  }
?>
```

img.inc.php:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once('myfunctions.inc.php');
  require_once('../class/myclass.class.php');
  $oData = new myclass();
  header('Content-Type: image/png');
  $sPanelModel = $_SESSION['produit'];
  $sEtiquette = '../img/etiquettes/label_'.$sPanelModel.'_preview.png';
  $rImg = imagecreatefrompng($sEtiquette);
  imagepng($rImg);
  imagedestroy($rImg);
?>
```

**Note: This code works if I comment require_once calling myclass.class.php.
Calling functions.inc.php works (only few functions).**

```
tree :
/
 + class
   + myclass.class.php
 + inc
   + functions.inc.php
   + img.inc.php
 + images
   + etiquettes
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve - why do you even use imagecreatefrompng() when you are just outputting the very same image? You could simply deliver it by using readfile(). I guess you will do something with your image ressource later... If it works when you comment the "require" declaration I would suspect that you might have multiple declarations of "myclass", or that in the file itself there is a blank line after ?>, thus outputting blanks. You might want to have another look.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This code is the beginning, i made step by step to be sure of my code. Later, i will make some loops to fill this first image.

Comment: Watch out for PHP error reporting, especially since 5.4. The error won't be printed on screen but will throw an error with the image. Try 'error_reporting(0);' at the top of your code, worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is true that it works by uncommenting the require() for myclass.class.php, then the most likely cause is this file contains blank lines (whitespace) before the `<?php` or after the `?>`. This would add Ascii characters to the output of the image, or insert a php error message (Headers could not be sent) on your header() statement and thus mess up your file.
However, as I mentioned in my comment, if your sole purpose is to output the picture you could use readfile() instead of creating an image instance.
Hope that helps,
Stefan

Comment: OMG ! Thanks a lot _ExternalUse_ ! I'm used to check for theses blank spaces at beginning of all my files, but this time I thought it was already done.