# JpGraph error in PHP image saving permission: "JpGraph Error: 25107"

Tags: php, jpgraph

My PHP JpGraph code displays error like

```
The image "http://localhost/jpeg/src/Examples/x.php" cannot be displayed
because it contains error
```

When I search the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493957/php-gd-the-image-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-contains-errors) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297900/php-gd-image-cannot-be-displayed-because-it-contains-errors), the main problem indicated was **white space** at the  beginning or end or the problem with the header. But I could not find a whitespace (I hope the header is okAY because it's a simplest manual example).

Just for a try, I tried to save the image instead of display in browser. But it showed another problem as **JpGraph Error: 25107 Can't write to file**, php process has no permission. But I couldnot solve the second error after searching some source. I worry whether I go wrong path and doing some blind thing. Can anyone direct me?

I use  the code to generate JpGraph:

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once('jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
require_once('jpgraph/jpgraph_matrix.php'); 

$data = array(
array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
array(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0),
array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
array(10,9,8,17,6,5,4,3,2,1,0),

); 

$graph = new MatrixGraph(400,300);
$graph->title->Set('Basic matrix example');
$graph->title->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_BOLD,14); 

 $mp = new MatrixPlot($data);
 $graph->Add($mp); 
//$graph->Stroke(); 
$graph->Stroke("myimage.png");
?>
```

Comment: To make sure that you don’t have whitespace before or after the image data, try saving the file from the browser (ctrl+s) and then opening it in a hex editor, thus avoiding the permission error.

Comment: You maybe have a warning or something printed inside the image. As Raphael says, try to save it to see if PHP doesn't add stupid things inside.

Comment: As I mentioned, directing png image to browser results in a black screen with displayed error **image"http://localhost/jpeg/src/Examples/x.php" cannot be displayed because it contains error**. I saved that  as png (ctrl+s). While opening the saved png file using gedit, shows "The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file you could corrupt this document.
You can also choose another character encoding and try again. (**But this warning error also there when opening a normal png file also**)

Comment: Thanks @RaphaelSchweikert and Jérôme Mahuet for the direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was a problem due to whites space, but in some of the source files. Here are the two steps I followed to overcome the error,

1. In the php.ini file, set the output buffering as 0 instead of 4096.
2. In the source files (jpgraph_matrix.php  and jpgraph_glayout_vh.inc.php), there were  some extra white space at the beginning and at the end. When done the first step (set the buffer), the white space containing files and lines were displayed in browser. When those lines were removed, the graph is generated.

Answer (score 0):

i just met this problem. "JpGraph Error: 25107 Can't write to file ...." 
i change the permission of the image file.
chmod 777 filename. 
and then it works.
hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this

require_once ('jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('jpgraph/src/jpgraph_pie.php');
// Some data

$data = array(30,70);

// Create the Pie Graph. 
$graph = new PieGraph(350,250);

$theme_class="DefaultTheme";
//$graph->SetTheme(new $theme_class());

// Set A title for the plot
//$graph->title->Set("A Simple Pie Plot");
$graph->SetBox(true);

// Create
$p1 = new PiePlot($data);
$graph->Add($p1);

$p1->ShowBorder();
$p1->SetColor('black');
$p1->SetSliceColors(array('#baeeff','#1ac6ff'));
//$graph->Stroke();
$graph->Stroke(dirname(__FILE__).'/images/pieChart.png');

//Image URL like:http://localhost/jpgraph_text/images/pieChart.png
echo '<img src="'.$image_url.'" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by extra whitespace on the page. Make sure you don't have any spaces or line breaks before your opening <?php tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use root path to access your file.

```
$fileName = dirname(__FILE__, 5).'/uploads/invoices/g.jpg';
```